# Moment.js Accept both 12-hour and 24-hour time

Tags: javascript, parsing, momentjs

Is there a way in Moment.js to accept both 12-hour and 24-hour times in an input filed.

For example

```
var myField= $('#myField').val();
var validTime = moment(myField, [h:mm A]).format(HHmm);
```

I would like to accept:

- 12-hour format: '2:35 pm'
- 24-hour format: '14:35'

I can't find any documentation on parsing multiple formats.  Perhaps I should test the value using a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply use an array of formats.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

```
var validTime = moment(myField, ["h:mm A", "H:mm"]);
```

Comment: 4m1r, thanks for answering this question!  You sure hit the nail on the head.  I overlooked this in the documentation and couldn't find anything with a quick google search....  It should have stood out to me since it was an array :P  Anyhow, thanks again!

Comment: Ya, I wouldn't have noticed that either.  Good luck.  =)

Comment: In fairness to you, @CharlesK.Henry, I also have difficulty finding stuff in momentjs' documentation.